# OS Workflow Replacement

Tags: java, workflow, jbpm, activiti, opensymphony

We have a Java application that uses Open-Symphony workflow, we are re-designing this application and trying to replace OS Workflow with new open-source workflow engines, since OS WF has reached its final stages. What would be the best possible replacement of this OS workflow ?

Workflow should facilitate current steps, persist history steps, actions, pre and post conditions for each step.

I looked into JBPM and Activiti workflows, but this looked pretty heavy for my application as they come with more features.

Any thoughts would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

My first contribution to the jbpm (early drools flow) project was the support for osworkflow features. Jbpm is ultra flexible and what you can do is to create simple semantic on top of it and use the core engine only to serve your needs.

Comment: Thanks for your reply salaboy, Finally I decided to go with JBPM 6.0.0 version.